# PHP progress bar on download

Tags: php, download, zip, progress

I wrote a PHP code for site backup and I am compressing the whole site and allowing the user to download it in his/her machine. The compression and download works fine but since it is a site backup, it is taking some time to zip and download and I don't want the user to navigate to any other page while the zip/download is in progress. Is there any way, I can show a progress bar while zip/download is in progress? I searched in google but it seems that you can show progress bar on upload but not while downloading.

I created a temp file before the zip actually takes place and did a check if the file exists. My logic was if the file exist then display a modal dialog in JS with "please wait.." message but since the download makes use of header, I cannot basically echo anything before download.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Yes, there are many you can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719931/update-the-progress-bar-on-file-downloading

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fake progress bar using a gif animation...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SubmitForm() {
    StartProgress();
    var backup = document.getElementById("backup");
    backup.submit();
  }
  function StartProgress() {
    ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src", 100);
    return true;
  }
  </script>

  <form id="backup" action="backup.php" method="post">
    <input class="backup" type="submit" name="backup" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="BackUp">
  </form>
  <div style="display: none" id="progress"><img id="progress_image" src="css/progress_bar.gif" alt="BackUp in progress..."></div>
```

**Here you can see my idea working... please click on BackUp button to test it...**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: #C0C0C0 3px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 270px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
}
.backup {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #C0C0C0 3px solid;
  box-shadow: inset -5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 5px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#progress {
  padding: 20px;
}
.cleardiv {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BackUp Demo Progress Bar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SubmitForm() {
    StartProgress();
    var backup = document.getElementById("backup");
    backup.submit();
  }
  function StartProgress() {
    ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src", 100);
    return true;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<form id="backup" action="backup.php" method="post">
<input class="backup" type="submit" name="backup" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="BackUp">
</form>
<div style="display: none" id="progress">
<img id="progress_image" src="http://www.1sttry.de/files/specials/progressbars/ProgressBar23466666.gif" alt="BackUp in progress...">
</div>
<div class="cleardiv"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then search a gif animation in order to display a progress bar...

[Google + ajax + loader + gif](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20loader%20gif&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2ZBUVfCTDISp7Abb34O4A)

I hope this helps :)