# How to load progress bar "on click" using php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show progress while the php script runs so the user doesn't click the send button twice in welcome.php but this displays processing not on click but after the action is completed while my intention is to do it onclick while the action gets executed.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Processing . . .";
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="ratings.php" method="post">
        Insert URL :
        <input type="text" name="id">
        <br> Number Of Reviews:
        <input type="number" name="number">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    <p id="display"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think (https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) will help you. Use jquery for same.

Comment: I would think your form gets submitted / the page reloaded when you click the button. Unless there is more code that you are not showing.

Comment: after submit action ur page reload :) add echo processing to ratings.php into begin of the this file

Comment: @AlexKashin I echoed "Processing" at begin of the ratings.php script and "Done" at the end of ratings.php script which gets displayed after the script gets executed at once so I believe this is not the solution

Comment: Read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220074/php-progress-bar-on-download/30237129#30237129 I think you can adapt to your needs :)

Comment: I posted some code below, try it :) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30486398/4432311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, what you can do is on click, show the progress bar and submit your form via `AJAX.`

After PHP processing of the form is complete, you may move the page to another page using `window.location`

I guess this is the best practice given the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery version. Instead of submit button use a span or div with id. and while click span trigger the code and submit the form.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="ratings.php" method="post" id="ratings">
            Insert URL :
            <input type="text" name="id">
            <br> Number Of Reviews:
            <input type="number" name="number">
            <br>
            <!-- Add css to make the span look like button -->
            <span id="submit_form">Submit</span>
        </form>
        <span id="display"></span>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Initialize submitted with false
            var submitted = false;
            // Onclick Submit span.
            $("#submit_form").click(function(){
                $("#display").html("Processing....");
                // Form is submitted.
                if(!submitted)
                {
                    // Submitting the form using its id.
                    $("#ratings").submit();
                }
                // On first click submitted will be change to true.
                // On the next click the submitted variable will be as true.
                // So the above if condition will not be executed after the first time.
                if(!submitted)
                    submitted= true;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Update**

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mahendranmails/c43e3utx/1/

Hope it'll help you..

**Update**

As per suggestion of @ibad-gore you can able to use ajax to process the php file without reloading the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="ratings.php" method="post" id="ratings">
        Insert URL :
        <input type="text" name="id">
        <br> Number Of Reviews:
        <input type="number" name="number">
        <br>
        <!-- Add css to make the span look like button -->
        <span id="submit_form">Submit</span>
    </form>
    <span id="display"></span>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Initialize submitted with false
        var submitted = false;
        var form=$("#ratings");
        $("#submit_form").click(function(){
            $("#display").html("Processing....");
            // Form is submitted.
            if(!submitted)
            {
                // Submitting the form using ajax.
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:form.attr("action"),
                    data:$("#ratings input").serialize(),//only input
                    success: function(response, status){
                        if(status=="success")
                        {
                            submitted = false;
                            $("#display").html("Submitted");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            // On first click submitted will be change to true.
            // On the next click the submitted variable will be as true.
            // So the above if condition will not be executed after the first time.
            if(!submitted)
                submitted= true;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does the same thing doesn't resolve the purpose

Comment: From your question i understood that while submit the form you need to show the `processing` in the `#display` element and also when the user clicks second time or after a click, the form should not submit. So the above code will work for this concept. I tested it. Please test the code and let me know. If I misunderstood please reply with a clear question.

Comment: added fiddle. take a look.

Comment: True :) but it doesn't work because I am running a long script and lot of process is also involved --- to be specific I am generating a report of more than 1000 records written to an excel sheet please suggest an alternative because it doesn't work till all the script is done executing --- I am not sure if action gets invoked before correct me if I am wrong thank you for your time and effort

Comment: doesn't work means you haven't get the `processing...` text on clicking `submit` or you are able to submit the form using second click? Please tell me clearly. I haven't get you properly. Which is not working?

Comment: I have echoed "done" at the end of ratings.php script so I am getting done on execution of the script. After execution if I click the back button I can see "processing..." displayed so my intention was to display the same during the execution of the script so I commented it doesn't work as intended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78911/discussion-between-mahendran-and-prabhu-konchada).

Answer (score 1):

Try my answer, I tested it and works fine for me, let's me know if it's as you wanted...

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: #C0C0C0 3px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 270px;
  height: 240px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
}
.rating {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #C0C0C0 3px solid;
  box-shadow: inset -5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 5px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#progress {
  padding: 20px;
}
.cleardiv {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ratings</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function SubmitForm() {
        StartProgress();
        var rating = document.getElementById("rating");
        rating.submit();
      }
      function StartProgress() {
        ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
        document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src", 100);
        return true;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <form id="rating" action="ratings.php" method="post">
        Insert URL:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="id">
        <br><br>
        Number Of Reviews:
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="number">
        <br><br>
        <input class="rating" type="submit" name="rating" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="Rate It">
      </form>
      <div style="display: none" id="progress">
        <img id="progress_image" src="http://www.1sttry.de/files/specials/progressbars/ProgressBar23466666.gif" alt="Task in progress...">
      </div>
      <div class="cleardiv"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to scroll the snippet otherwise you cannot see the progress bar :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ButtonClicked()
{
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
   return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
</script>
```

Create two buttons and hide one

```
<input id="buttonreplacement" style="display:none;" type="submit"  Value="Processing . . .">
<input  id="formsubmitbutton" type="submit" Value="Submit">
```